# DirectX11 Particle simulation over deferred scene

Tags: directx, directx-11, hlsl, particles

I'm fairly new to Directx, but I have implemented a program which uses Deferred shading and are now going to create a particle system. But as I try to render the final image, I see that my particles are appearing on top of my previously rendered scene, so I am wondering in what order I should render the techniques, or how to get the billboarded quad to appear where it is supposed to be in the scene.
[image: Final Image]

This is how my final scene looks, don't worry about the unfinished shadow mapping.

This is the current flow:

1. Geometry pass, render entire scene with all 3D objects and put normals, position, diffusion etc into gbuffers (Vertex and pixel shader)
2. Light pass, using the gbuffers and lightinfo depthmaps etc to do light and shadow calculations (computeshader)
3. Particle simulation, create points in computeshader and then use geometry shader to perform billboarding (computeshader, vertexshader, geometryshader and pixelshader)

I am a bit perplexed, since the result of my deferred shading is an image, how and where will the particle simulation come in? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Forgot to set my particle blendstate, so here you can see how the quad is supposed to look like, but the problem that it renders over all objects still persists.
https://imgur.com/a/BukFS8L

Comment: Particle system rasterization states still need to be set to read (but not write to) the depth buffer.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio How does one set the rasterstate to just read? Only thing I can find in the D3D11_RASTRIZER_DESC is the depth bias, do I have to set that one, or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... D3D11 has the  `D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC` you can fill in to configure state for the depth buffer.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio yes I figured it had something to do with the Depth Stencil, so I have created another depthStencilState and depthStencilDesc which I switch to before rendering my particle system. I am however confused about what parameters in the depthStencilDesc I should change. I thought it was DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO, but all that changed was creating the additive blending, it still renders over all objects: https://imgur.com/a/ThfDmJh

Comment: What value have you set for `DepthEnable`? It should be `TRUE` because your particle system rendering still needs to perform depth testing. Also what's the value for `DepthFunc`? You can probably use the same comparison function for normal opaque rendering.

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio This is the depthstencil I currently use for my particles: https://imgur.com/a/9epXDvk
And this is the normal one I use for everything else: https://imgur.com/a/mFR0JCD

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio I realized that my problem might be becausemy vertexshader doesn't really draw any vertices, I create points in a computeshader and then I create quads from those points in the geometry shader, so how would I even get them into the depth buffer?

Comment: I also implemented a particle system with the geometry shader to produce quads from point vertices passed in by the vertex shader. I'm not sure how using a compute shader to generate the vertices will affect the pipeline, but I imagine if the geometry shader still outputs triangles to the pixel shader, then normal rasterization and blending should work as expected? Perhaps you can test this theory with a vertex shader as input to the geometry shader, and see if this impacts the final render?

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio ah, sorry if I was unclear, but thats what I do! The computeshader is just for updating points, then I use a Vertexshader to send those points to a geometryshader which creates quads and billboards, and then a pixelshader that applies texture. But I dont use IASetInputLayout, so no vertices are actually drawn in the vertex shader, but I am unsure if that is where the problem lies